# Why are some SQLite functions zero-based and some one-based

Tags: sqlite, parameters

The index parameter for [`sqlite3_column_*`](http://www.sqlite.org/capi3ref.html#sqlite3_column_blob) is zero-based while [`sqlite3_bind_*`](http://www.sqlite.org/capi3ref.html#sqlite3_bind_blob) is one-based.

Is there a reason for this?

Answer (score 2):

I've got it.

Blame [sqlite3_bind_parameter_index](http://www.sqlite.org/c3ref/bind_parameter_index.html):

> Return the index of an SQL parameter given its name. The index value returned is suitable for use as the second parameter to sqlite3_bind(). A zero is returned if no matching parameter is found.

So there you go. Odd choice, considering they seem to be using a signed int for the index, meaning they could have used -1 to indicate a no-match. Maybe the reason behind *that* is more historical, SQLite has been around for a while...